# Focus on a FrameworkElementFactory in WPF

Tags: wpf, setfocus, frameworkelementfactory

I am using a FrameworkElementFactory as the following code in my WPF program:

```
FrameworkElementFactory txt1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
```

I tried to programmatically focus on this FrameworkElementFactory and also tried it with VisualTreeHelper.HitTest. Is there any way to focus on *txt1 * like `txt1.Focus` or HitTest ?

I created it on Listview and filled in its columns programmatically. And design this Listview according to the following codes:

```
 for (int x = 0; x <= obj.ClmnDegerler.Length - 1; x++)
      {
        var GridViewColumn1 = new GridViewColumn();
        txt1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        txt1.SetValue(TextBox.HeightProperty, 20.0);
        txt1.SetValue(TextBox.WidthProperty, clmnwidth);

        dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        dataTemplate.VisualTree = txt1; 

        GridViewColumn1.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
        this.UGridview1.Columns.Add(GridViewColumn1);
      }
```

And I created a button by xaml and when I want to click the button I want to focus on txt1

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //txt1.Focus(); not working
        }
```

Comment: You must know that FrameworkElementFactoty is deprecated. Maybe you like to provide information on what you are trying to achieve, so that one can help you to do it in a cleaner/simpler way.

Comment: I changed my question.

Comment: Looks like `txt1` is just a template to be instantiated per gridview row. You could only focus a specific instantiation within a single row. Which row should be focused, when the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes it must be like that. Thanks.